# Understanding a particular chord progression

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions

In this particular chord progression (appeared in a Jacob Collier video), I'm trying to understand the meaning of all the successors to each chord.

I undertand **F9/A - Abm13b5 - Gm11** as II7-V7-IMaj7 in EbMaj.

**Cm11-Bbm11** can be understood as iii-ii

But I can't understand Bbm11 - D7#9#11/A - Abm11, can you help me with this one ?

[image]

Comment: Your 1st premise doesn't seem right. Key there is Bb, so Gm won't be I. Even without the extensions, the RN doesn't seem right, in any key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

There are two fancied-up **iii-vi-ii-V** progressions in F and Gb major, respectively.

---

The chord symbols in this case are an attempt to give a more-or-less literal translation of the written chord — that is, indicating all of the pitches present — rather than a functional one.

To begin deciphering them, note that in the first measure F is a pedal tone, and in the second measure, Ab is a pedal tone.

Considering that F is not a chord tone in each case, leaves us with

`A-7b5  –  Ab-7b5  —  G-7(add11)  —  C-7`

However, the C in the G-7(add11) is also not a functional pitch. It's an anticipation of the resolution to the following C-7. Thus:

`A-7b5  —  Ab-7b5  —  G-7  —  C-7`

Or, even more simply

`A-7  –  Ab-7  –  G-7  –  C-7`

A similar process allows for simplification of the second measure. The first chord reduces to `Bb-7`, the second to `Ao7`, the third to `Ab-7`, and the fourth to `Db7`, which resolves into `GbM7`.

`Bb-7  –  Ao7  —  Ab-7  —  Db7  —  GbM7`

Now, allowing that the second chord in each measure is a tritone substitution, we have something like

```
F: iii  —  vi  —  ii  —  V
Gb: iii  —  vi  —  ii  —  V  — I
```